# In Javascript declarations, what does "?" along with ":" mean?

Tags: javascript, variable-declaration

In a Javascript program to convert a Julian day to a calendar day, the following code is seen:

```
 month = (G<13.5) ? (G-1) : (G-13)
  year = (month<2.5) ? (C-4715) : (C-4716)
```

I thought these may have been some sort of conditions that changed the values of `month` or `year` according to the values of the variables within their declarations My research has returned nothing on these symbols--particularly the "?"--showing up in Javascript code.

For a complete view of the source, visit astronomy.villanova.edu/links/jd.htm

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ternary or [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Indeed, that is much better duplicate. )

Comment: As one of the comments said in "Question mark in JavaScript", this is very hard to search within a search engine. My apologies on having a duplicate question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the [ternary or conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) operators in javascript

It is a short hand for something like:

```
if(a ==0){
   b = 1;
}
else{
   b = 0;
}
```

Comment: No; it's called the conditional operator.

Comment: @SLaks Please check the posted link. It can be called both

Answer (score 0):

variable = if condition is true ? give this answer : otherwise give this one;

so int x = 5;
int y = x==5? 10 :12; 
would mean if x is equal to 5, y would be 10 , otherwise it would be 12